# Define multiplication as $(a,b) \boxdot (c,d)=(ac-bd(r^2+s^2), ad+bc+2rbd)$ where $a,b,c,d,r\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\neq s\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Define multiplication as $(a,b) \boxdot (c,d)=(ac-bd(r^2+s^2), ad+bc+2rbd)$ where $a,b,c,d,r\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\neq s\in \mathbb{R}$. The multiplicative inverse is $(1,0)$. I need to show that every ordered pair other than $(0,0)$ has a multiplicative inverse.

How on earth can I show that this property is satisfied (or produce a counterexample)? I'm trying to do this in the most elementary way possible. I do not have a background in abstract algebra and this problem should be done using basic algebra with an understanding of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two linear equations in $c$ and $d$.  You know the right-hand side is $(1,0)$.

Comment: And you can simplify the equations some by letting $A = r^2 + s^2$ and $B = 2r$, making it a little less messy to work with.

Comment: Like this $ac-bd(r^2+s^2)=1$ and $ad+bc+2rbd=0$?

Comment: $ac-bdA=1$ and $ad+bc+Bbd=0$